# InkPresenter draw only in transparent area

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have an InkPresenter and this image with a transparent background. I want my strokes to be drawn only in the transparent area and ignore the black border of the shape. How is it possible? [image: image to draw]

Comment: clipping can perhaps help you here. could you share some example code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem using Opacity Mask:

```
<InkPresenter.OpacityMask>
     <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImageMask}" />
</InkPresenter.OpacityMask>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an example using WPF, same applies to InkPresenter, you can use `InkPresenter.Clip` property to define the clip region

```
<Border BorderBrush="Green"
        BorderThickness="1"
        Width="200"
        Height="200">
    <Grid>
        <InkCanvas>
            <InkCanvas.Clip>
                <EllipseGeometry  RadiusX="98"
                                  RadiusY="98"
                                  Center="100,100" />
            </InkCanvas.Clip>
        </InkCanvas>
        <Ellipse Stroke="Blue"
                 StrokeThickness="2" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

result

[image: result]

Comment: The thing is, I wanted the clip to be done according to an image, not a shape. I solved it using OpacityMask.

Comment: Great find! an opacity mask is perfectly fine as long as the transparent region is based on as image. a geometry based clip can be used when there is a need of scalable mask. happy coding :)